# box-shadow both inset and outside on same div

Tags: css

Can't I have both box shadow inner and outer on the same div?
I've tried but it doesn't work

http://jsfiddle.net/CWuw8/

```css
div{
    top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px inset;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
}

body{background: #d14343}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to use comma to separate both shadows: http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/CWuw8/3/

And you must also specify the color for your shadow in order for it to be seen.

```css
div{
    top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 
        10px 10px 10px #000, 
        inset 0 0 10px #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
}

body{background: #d14343}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using CSS3 you can have multple box shadows just by seperating them by commas eg:

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px, 0 0 10px inset;
```

You can have as many as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Added a runable code snippet:

```css
div {
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5),
    0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, .5) inset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
}

body {
  background: #fff
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```